# Surface Area of a Spheroid in Python

Tags: python-3.x, geometry

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the surface area of a prolate or oblate spheroid. Here's a link to where I got the formulas (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroid & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroid). I think I've written them wrong, but here is my code so far;

```
from math import pi, sqrt, asin, degrees, atanh 

def checkio(height, width):
    height = float(height) 
    width = float(width) 
    my_list = []
    if height == width:
        r = 0.5 * width
        surface_area = 4 * pi * r**2
        surface_area = round(surface_area, 2) 
        my_list.append(surface_area)
    elif height > width: #If spheroid is prolate 
        a = 0.5 * width
        b = 0.5 * height
        e2 = 1 - a**2 / b**2
        e = sqrt(e2) 
        surface_area = 2 * pi * a**2 * (1 + b / (a * e) * asin(e)))
        surface_area = round(surface_area, 2) 
        my_list.append(surface_area) 
    elif height < width: #If spheroid is oblate 
        a = 0.5 * width
        b = 0.5 * height
        e2 = 1 - b**2 / a**2
        e = sqrt(e2) 
        surface_area = 2 * pi * a**2 * (1 + (1 - e2) / e * atanh(e))
        surface_area = round(surface_area, 2)
        my_list.append(surface_area)
    return my_list
```

Comment: Where you have weight, I think you mean width.  And writing your function like this, you are not dealing with the case where height is equal to width.

Comment: `height = float(width)`?! Neither of those cases will ever run, as `height == weight` every time.

Comment: Sorry, I was tired when I wrote this, fixed it.

Comment: Ok, now you need to define a, b, and e within your function.  

I am not clear why you have lst defined as a list.  Are you going to have multiple results in lst?

Comment: Sorry about a, b and e, I don't know how I forgot to add them. And yes, eventually the list will have volume of the spheroid as well as surface area, I didn't add the volume part though.

Comment: Ok, now I've got a math domain error on e = sqrt(e2) from the last elif statement.

Comment: Ok, it looks like a is half height for your prolate spheroid, and b is half width.  It is different for prolate and oblate.

Comment: Try to solve the challenge http://www.checkio.org/mission/humpty-dumpty without cheating :P